# jquery is removing elements after repeated image click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

This has broken me

My code functions as intended, where a user clicks an image, and the other images change source and become URL links. There are 6 images in total, each will have their own alternative images/URLs upon being clicked.

My code focuses on the first and second image

A user will click the first image, and the images fade out and in. One image becomes a reset icon, which reverts the images to how they began. but if the user repeats this process, the reset icon has jquery behind it that seems to remove the elements from their container and this ruins the overall page experience. I can see that style HTML is added to the images after the initial click.

I cannot work out how to stop the elements from vanishing, thus retaining the important structure

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
$(function () { //Open function for 1st Logo
  $("#SHI").click (function() { //Click starts Logo change
    $("#SHI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
      $(this).wrap("<a href='https://www.random.org/'>").attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","IMI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200)//Swap Logo image, ID and adds URL
      $("#BPI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
        $(this).wrap("<a href='https://www.random.org/p'>").attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","img6").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200) //Swap Logo image, ID and adds URL
        $("#THI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
          $(this).wrap("<a href='https://www.random.org/'>").attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","img7").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200)//Swap Logo, ID and adds URL
          $("#EMI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fade Out Last Icon for Logo set
            $(this).attr('src', "https://i.picsum.photos/id/181/1920/1189.jpg?hmac=s_EdeBmW8NMdklpios9-zKgZP8bt2_OZ8djbmrPGpYE").attr("id","EXI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).click(function() {//Fades in "reset" icon, add click.
              $("#IMI").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","SHI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#img6").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","BPI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#img7").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","THI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#EXI").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","EMI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
             }); //Closes "reset"
            }); //Closes fade
         }) //Closes fade 
        }); //Closes fade
      }); //Closes fade
    }); //Closes click function
});//Closes Logo change


$(function() { //Open function for 2nd Logo
  $("#BPI").click(function() { //Click starts Logo change
    $("#SHI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
      $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","IMI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200).wrap("<a href='https://www.random.org/'>") //Swap Logo image, ID and adds URL
      $("#BPI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
        $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","img6").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200).wrap("<https://www.random.org/'>") //Swap Logo image, ID and adds URL
        $("#THI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out Logo
          $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","img7").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(200).wrap("<https://www.random.org/'>")//Swap Logo, ID and adds URL
          $("#EMI").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fade Out Last Icon for Brand Support Logo set
            $(this).attr('src', "https://i.picsum.photos/id/181/1920/1189.jpg?hmac=s_EdeBmW8NMdklpios9-zKgZP8bt2_OZ8djbmrPGpYE").attr("id","EXI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).click(function() {//Fades in "reset" icon, add click.
              $("#IMI").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","SHI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#img6").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","BPI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#img7").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","THI").attr("style","grid-item").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#EXI").fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100/200").attr("id","EMI").fadeIn(300).unwrap()});//Fades out support icon, resets ID and removes URL
              }); //Closes "reset"
            }); //Closes img3 fade
          }) //Closes img2 fade 
        }); //Closes img1 fade
      }); //Closes img fade
    }); //Closes click function
}); //Closes Logo change

});
```

```css
.section {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 300px);  /* 3 columns */
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px); /* 2 rows  */
    grid-gap: 50px 50px; /* 50 pixels of space added between rows and 100 pixels added between columns  */
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1%;
    border-bottom: #02AB9D;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.grid-item{
    width: 200;
    height: 50;
    justify-content: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GSH"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="SHI" class="SHC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GBP"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="BPI" class="BPC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GTH"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="THI" class="THC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GEM"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="EMI" class="EMC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GET"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="ETI" class="ETC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
        <div class="grid-item" ID="GJM"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" ID="JMI" class="JMC" alt="some text" width="300" height="50"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear from your description or code what you are trying to accomplish. I see a lot of places where things can be optimized, but I am not sure what you want, so I am not sure how to advise.

Comment: Hello, and thank you.
The end result should be that a user has six unique images (or brand logos). For each logo they click, all the other logos fade out and new logos will fade in. One icon will be for manuals, another for a FAQ section etc. Each of these icons becomes a clickable link to another page. But, for the ease of the user, I want one of the icons to act as a back button, should the user accidentally choose the wrong brand. It's this back icon causing issues. If I choose a brand, then press the back icon, then choose a brand and hit the back icon again, the grid elements vanish.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the .unwrap element.
When you use .unwrap with no value in the parenthesis, jquery removes the parent element from the element specified in the function. Each iteration of this function will remove further parents of the element you select in the function. So if you have something you want unwrapped with 3 divs, it will take three calls of the .unwrap() to break the appearance of your site.

To avoid that, you need to specify the element that you want to unwrap in the same way you specify what you wanted to wrap around your target element.

Use:

```
.unwrap(["your element"])
```